# Check if the artifacts are generated and exist in GitHub CI

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

```
      - name: Build Debug APK
        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug
        
      - name: Get Debug APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-debug
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
          
      - name: Build Signed APK
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease
        
      - name: Sign Android release
        uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
        with:
          releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/release
          signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
          alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
          keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
          keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
          
      - name: Get Release APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: app-release
          path: ${{ env.SIGNED_RELEASE_FILE }}
      - name: Check debug apk existence
        id: check_debug
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v1
        with:
          files: "app-debug.apk"
          
      - name: Missing Debug APK
        if: steps.check_debug.outputs.files_exists == 'false'
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
          subject: Github Actions job result
          body: Build job of ${{github.repository}} is incomplete, Debug APK missing!
          to: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          from: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          
      - name: Contains Debug APK
        if: steps.check_debug.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
          subject: Github Actions job result
          body: Build job of ${{github.repository}} completed successfully, Debug APK exists!
          to: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          from: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          
      - name: Check release apk existence
        id: check_release
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v1
        with:
          files: "app-release.aab"  
        
      - name: Missing Release APK
        if: steps.check_release.outputs.files_exists == 'false'
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
          subject: Github Actions job result
          body: Build job of ${{github.repository}} is incomplete, Release APK missing!
          to: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          from: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          
      - name: Contains Release APK
        if: steps.check_release.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.MAIL_PASSWORD}}
          subject: Github Actions job result
          body: Build job of ${{github.repository}} completed successfully, Release APK exists!
          to: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
          from: ${{secrets.MAIL_USERNAME}}
```

After generating the APK files for my Android repo, I want the GitHub CI to send me an email to notify me that the artifacts are generated. So here I have an action to check if the APK name exists and regardless of the result, send me an email.

These artifacts are generated successfully but I get the emails saying they don't exist.

What went wrong in my script?

Answer (score 3):

By the way, I have got a slightly different use case but needed to check if an artifact exists prior to doing some other steps.

Stumbled across this need and found no way of checking if some artifact exists. So created a new action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-artifact-existence

You can add a new step that is going to expose and output denoting if an artifact exists or not by the given artifact name:

```yaml
uses: xSAVIKx/artifact-exists-action@v0
id: check_coverage_artifact
with:
  name: 'coverage-artifact'
```

Then you can use `steps.check_coverage_artifact.outputs.exists` (true/false) in the conditions.

Comment: thanks, works as intended. the example given is wrong though. using `uses: xSAVIKx/artifact-exists-action@v0` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` as an upload path but on the other hand you're checking `app-debug.apk` for existence.

Comment: I rewrote my logic and it is working now. Thanks for answering

Comment: @calvert should mark it as the accepted answer.